# Express File Serving and Static Files

Tags: node.js, express, static-files

Hey everyone I was unaware and what to search for this issue, but here is my problem. For our project, we are sharing a server for our applications using express. We are not allowed to share the urls, so I will have to change the url for the sake of the question. Our server root is http://www.server.com, but our project url is http://www.server.com/team01/. How can I serve from /team01/public/css/whatever.css every single time, but keep our files for testing on localhost. I don't want to have to change the links every single time I migrate from localhost to the server. Also for all of our href it is going to server.com which is messing up everything for migrating from localhost to the server. Any help is appreciated. I've used 
 app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'))); in express.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML files, you can reference:

```
<link href="/css/whatever.css">
```

This will tell the browser to use whatever host the web page was loaded from, but to always request the `/css/whatever.css` path on that host.

Then, your express server can use this:

```
 app.use(express.static("/team01/public"));
```

This will tell the express server that when it receives a request for `/css/whatever.css`, it should look in `/team01/public/css/whatever.css` to see if the file exists and, if so, serve it statically from there.

Using this scheme, you should be able to run on localhost just fine as long as you have a copy of the right files in `/team01/public` on your localhost server.  Then, when you switch over to the real `http://www.server.com`, you just have to make sure you also copy over the `/team01/public` files to that host.

---

FYI, you can also add a `<base href="http://server.com/fa17">` to the head of every web page on your site and then that will be used with all relevative URLs in the pages.  If you use a template engine for serving your HTML files, then you can control what that path is automatically in that tag via your startup code (based on where your server is running).

Comment: I'm still having the same issue. I've logged the path of the directory on the server and this is where the files are located for public /home/fa17/public_html/team07/public how should I handle this? When I link with <link href="/css/whatever.css"> it goes straight to the root and not /fa17/css. When I take out the forward slash in the beginning it works, but it becomes a nightmare for paths that are not at the root to keep changing depending on where the path is located.

Comment: @Vik - If the URL `/css/whatever.css` should load the file that is located at `/home/fa17/public_html/team07/public/css/whatever.css`, then you should be able to just use `<link href="/css/whatever.css">` in the web page and `app.use(express.static("/home/fa17/public_html/team07/public"));`.

Comment: I've just done that and it's still not working... Even for all my anchor tags it's doing the same <a href="/login">Login</a> is referencing the base of the server to server.com/login and not server.com/fa17/login... Is there anything I can do in Nginx to fix this or is this a lost cause? I've managed to make it work on the server by appending /fa17/login, but that would be difficult to keep changing when I work locally. For the css it also works if I append /fa17g07/css/login.css, so I'm not sure what is going on or how to diagnose this issue. Thank you for your help so far by the way

Comment: @Vik - I didn't realize this was a system wide issue for all your requests, not just static resource requests.  I guess I don't really understand the overall problem you have.

Comment: @Vik - Why do you need the URL to be prefixed with `http://server.com/fa17`?  Is there an NGINX proxy looking for the `/fa17` path and redirecting to your particular private server?

Comment: @Vik - I added a note about possibly using `<base href="...">`.  Also not sure why you just filed a duplicate of this question.

Comment: Sorry I had thought I had referenced this question more along with express which I realized by your answers, but I felt I should tailor a question more towards nginx and static file serving. I think that may solve it with base href I will try it out first thing in the morning! I will let you know if it works

Comment: Did not get the notification for the note for the base href, but thanks for that! Will update tmrw

Comment: Was able to get it to work with the base tag! Such a useful html tag. You have just saved me so much time and taught me something new thank you so much!